# How to replace soldered valve with push in connect?

Tags: plumbing, valve

Attached diagram is for my main water shut off valve in my 2nd floor condominium. Existing valve is gate valve which has stopped working. I am no longer able to shut off water supply.

Copper pipe is coming out of wall and going back inside, I want to replace valve with push in connect (shark bite) valve.

I will be shutting off water supply to my unit from valve pit (dedicated to my unit)outside the building before I replace it.

My plan is to cut out copper pipe near both end of valve to remove it. But I don't know how I can fit the push in connect between solid coper lines. For push in connect valve I have to push valve onto pipe and I have to do that on both ends. I have to cut both ends to leave enough room that I can fit new valve but same time, I have to push new valve onto both ends of pipe, I can't imagine if I will be able to push enough length of solid pipe ends inside the valve fitting.

Any thoughts ?

[image]

Comment: What kind of solder (rosin) ..? silver (brazed) ..? Or do you have a plan for removing it already..?

Comment: Could you add dimensions to that sketch, or hold up a tape measure and take pics of the actual setup? There may be enough flex, even if stiff copper tubing, to enable you to get the push-connect fittings in.

Answer (score 1):

Well since you want to use a shark bite you may not like my solution.

I would cut both sides make a U shape. This is how I would sweat in a new valve on the left with a standard sleeve on right , you could do it with shark bites but this is how some plumbers would do it without kinking the copper.

Measure everything so when you push them together they both slip on.
Using copper sweat fittings they can be adjusted before sweating.